# Center math in table, bad centering

Tags: tables

I have next code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.3mm}

\begin{document}
    \section{Задача}
    Обчислити роботу, яку потрібно витрати, щоб відкачати воду з вертикальної циліндричної діжки радіусом 2м та висотою 22м.
    \begin{table}[H]
        \label{q:1:constants}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|m{4.2cm}|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \centering Костанта&Позначення&Значення&Одиниця вимірювання\\
            \hline
            Прискорення вільного падіння & \(g\)&10&\(\frac{\text{м}}{\text{с}^2}\)\\
            \hline
            Густина води&\(\rho_\text{води}\)&1000&\(\frac{\text{кг}}{\text{м}^3}\)\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Необхідні фізичні велечини}
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \label{q1:formulas}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            Назва&Формула&Одиниці вимірювання\\
            \hline
            Механічна робота&\(A=Fl=mgh\)&Дж\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Формули}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

It produces
[image]
There is a problem with vertical centering of fraction and `\rho` letter in first table second row. How to fix this? The `p{<width>}` wont help.

Comment: Off-topic: You need to execute the `\label` instructions after, not before, the associated `\caption` instructions.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: In a Ukrainian-language scholarly publication that aspires to meet scientific typographic standards, is it ok to use cyrillic rather than latin letters for the units of length, time, volume, etc.? I.e., is it ok to write `\frac{\text{м}}{\text{с}^2}` instead of, say, loading the [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package and writing `\unit{\meter\per\second\squared}` (which will employ the standard latin-alphabet letters for the units of length and time)? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico No, I guess not, it isn't a standard, but actually I don't know. All physics books that I have been reading in school (like a year ago, I don't think that something have changed) really used to write ukrainian letters in units. So siunitx may not be a standard. A bit of context: I don't have to know about latex at all. I am an applied math&software student who found out that typesetting homework in latex is faster and has higher quality than handwriting it. I am learning it by myself for 6 months.

Comment: It was an homework from math analysis (known as Calculus in English-speaking countries), physical problem that have to be solved with integral appliance. I have to use physical units very rare, it was the first time. I do understand that siunitx is more convenient and standard way to display physics units but, I decided not to "flex" with latin units in front of the teacher because it is uncommon to me and maybe the teacher to see latin in units...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide this background information. I very much appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

This is easy to achieve by use `tblr` of `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Задача}
Обчислити роботу, яку потрібно витрати, щоб відкачати воду з вертикальної циліндричної діжки радіусом 2м та висотою 22м.
    \begin{table}[ht]
 \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {X[l,m] *{2}{Q[c, mode=math]} X[c, m, mode=math]},
             row{1}  = {c, mode=text},
             rowsep=3pt
             }
Костанта
    & Позначення
        & Значення
                & Одиниця вимірювання           \\
Прискорення вільного падіння 
    & g & 10    & \dfrac{\text{м}}{\text{с}^2}   \\
Густина води
    & \rho_{\mathrm{води}} 
        & 1000  & \dfrac{\text{кг}}{\text{м}^3}  \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Необхідні фізичні велечини}
\label{q:1:constants}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[l,m]  Q[c, mode=dmath] Q[c,m]},
             row{1}  = {c, mode=text},
             rowsep=3pt
             }
Назва
    &   Формула
        &   {Одиниці\\ вимірювання}\\
Механічна робота
    & A=Fl=mgh  & Дж            \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Формули}
\label{q1:formulas}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico, ups, it is a text! wrong column option ... corrected now.

Comment: Another environment to read documentation about :)

Answer (score 3):

If some of the material in the cells gets too close to some of the horizontal lines, I suggest using fewer horizontal lines. For that, I suggest you load the `booktabs` package and employ its user macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` instead of `\hline`. And, do use inline-fraction notation instead of `\frac`. Also, don't use vertical lines in a table. The vertical lines accomplish nothing useful, but they do a very good job of making the table look like a barred prison cell window...

To make the first table fit within the width of the textblock, I suggest a combination of (a) inserting a line break in the final column header and (b) using a `tabularx` environment to allow automatic line breaking, if needed, in the first column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% new:
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % raggedright, not full justification

\begin{document}

\section{Задача}

Обчислити роботу, яку потрібно витрати, щоб відкачати воду з вертикальної циліндричної діжки радіусом 2м та висотою 22м.

\begin{table}[ht]      
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L ccc @{}}
\toprule 
Костанта & Позначення & Значення & Одиниця \\
&&& вимірювання \\
\midrule
Прискорення вільного падіння & \(g\) & 10 & \(\textrm{м}/\textrm{с}^2\) \\
\addlinespace % insert vertical whitespace
Густина води & \(\rho_{\textrm{води}}\) & 1000 & \(\textrm{кг}/\textrm{м}^3\) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Необхідні фізичні велечини}
\label{q:1:constants}
\end{table}
    
\begin{table}[h] 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} lcc @{}}
\toprule
Назва & Формула & Одиниці \\
&& вимірювання\\
\midrule
Механічна робота & \(A=Fl=mgh\) & Дж \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Формули}
\label{q1:formulas}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately people to who I have to give this work don't like booktabs "line" tables. Sorry

Comment: @VladyslavRehan - Oh well, you can't please all people...